# Naturally spawned Zombie Village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created a new world recently, and went exploring in Spectator mode to find a suitable spot to set up camp. As I was zooming about, on the very first day, not 200 blocks from spawn and only 2 minutes of exploration, I spotted a village. Upon investigation, I found that the entire village was actually Zombie Villagers.

I figured this was weird, (though obviously a thing in-game, since... well... there it was), but after a little researching, I couldn't find anything about this phenomenon.

What are the chances of this actually happening?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki article on villages](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#Generation):

> "2% of villages will generate as zombie villages. In such villages, all generated villagers are instead zombie villagers, and all doors and torches are missing. [...]"

There's also a chance for a village to be attacked by a zombie siege as explained in another answer, but that can only occur at midnight, and since it's your first day in the world that's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

The villagers all becoming zombies is probably a consequence of a **Zombie Siege event**.

The Zombie siege event is only available each night and there is a 10% chance that a zombie siege will spawn.

Zombie villagers can result from a zombie attack. If any type of zombie kills a villager, there is a chance that the villager will transform into a zombie villager. (100% on Hard difficulty, 50% on Normal, 0% on Easy).

- [More info on Zombie Siege](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_siege)
- [More info on Zombie Villagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Zombie_villagers)

I hope that helped!

Comment: The information you posted is accurate, but does not apply to the asker since it's his/her very first day in the world.

Comment: I though't midnight events still applied in the first day at spawn, my bad! I upvoted your answer!

Comment: I hadn't considered that point, but it seems unlikely that midnight events occur on the first day, since the game starts at dawn (internal time 0) which is of course after midnight (internal time 18000).